# ASP.NET MVC - Url.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Can some one tell me if I how I can use **Url.Content** when my URL contains an embedded code nugget like below?

```
<a class='highslide' id="baseThumb" href="../../Helpers/ImageHandler.ashx?imageid=<%= Model.ImageIDs[0] %>&thumbnail=0">
<img runat="server" src="../../Helpers/ImageHandler.ashx?imageid=<%= Model.ImageIDs[0] %>&thumbnail=1" alt=""/>
</a>
```

My image above only gets display on my local development environment, never when I deploy to a server. The ImageHandler is not found due to the URL being incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% 
    var url = Url.Content("~/PATH/Helpers/ImageHandler.ashx?imageid="  + Model.ImageIDs[0]);
%>

<a class='highslide' id="baseThumb" href="<%=url%>&thumbnail=0">
<img runat="server" src="<%=url%>&thumbnail=1" alt=""/>
</a>
```

The ~/ in Url.Content will point to the root, so from there you will have to set the correct path to the ashx file.